# Are CuCl and Cu2Cl2 equivalent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

I have seen $\ce{CuCl}$ and $\ce{Cu2Cl2}$ used interchangeably; they seem to be equivalent. If that is the case, then why does the latter have the '$2$' subscripts?

Comment: Without more context, this is hard to judge. Consider $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$, which has a polycation.

Comment: I was looking at Sandmeyer reaction catalysts (high school course).

Comment: For this very special case, it might be that the typesetting is off (This is a shot in the dark). In the Sandmeyer reaction, Cu changes its oxidation state between +1 and +2. Could the subscripts erroneously refer to this? Please reevaluate the material with this in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\ce{Cu2Cl2}$ is actually the dimer of [cuprous(I) chloride $\ce{CuCl}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(I)_chloride). Cuprous chloride dimerises and also trimerises and tetramerises in **gas phase**. The molecular structures of the species are measured with Gas-Phase Electron Diffraction and Quantum Chemical Calculations. Some information about the various species of cuprous chloride is given here:<sup>[1]</sup>

> The molecular geometry of gaseous cuprous chloride oligomers was determined by gas-phase electron diffraction at two different temperatures. Quantum chemical calculations were also performed for $\ce{Cu_nCl_n (n=1–4)}$ molecules. A complex vapor composition was found in both experiments. Molecules of $\ce{Cu3Cl3}$ and $\ce{Cu4Cl4}$ were present at the lower temperature (689 K), while **dimeric molecules ($\ce{Cu2Cl2}$) were found in addition to the trimers and tetramers at the higher temperature (1333 K)**. All $\ce{Cu_nCl_n}$ species were found to have planar rings by both experiment and computation. The bond lengths from electron diffraction ($r_\mathrm g$) at 689 K are 2.166±0.008 Å and 2.141±0.008 Å and the $\ce{Cu-Cl-Cu}$ bond angles are 73.9±0.6° and 88.0±0.6° for the trimer and the tetramer, respectively. At 1333 K the bond lengths are 2.254±0.011 Å, 2.180±0.011 Å, and 2.155±0.011 Å, and the $\ce{Cu-Cl-Cu}$ bond angles 67.3±1.1°, 74.4±1.1°, and 83.6±1.1° for the dimer, trimer, and tetramer, respectively.

**Reference**

(1) Hargittai, M.; Schwerdtfeger, P.; Réffy, B.; Brown, R. The Molecular Structure of Different Species of Cuprous Chloride from Gas-Phase Electron Diffraction and Quantum Chemical Calculations. *Chem. Eur. J.* **2003,** *9* (1), 327–333. [DOI: 10.1002/chem.200390027](http://doi.org/10.1002/chem.200390027)

Comment: So, CuCl has no real existence? And is it a covalent molecule?

Comment: @user226375 it is a solid at room temperature. It just polymerizes in gas phase. It is ionic in nature and has various crystalline forms.

Comment: thanks for replying. Is it ionic in even gas phase?( where it exists in dimer form)

Comment: @user226375 no it is not ionic in  gas phase and it polymerizes