# Does Copper(I) Iodide have a dimer?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, halides

A qualitative test for the iodide ion involves reacting the salt solution with copper sulphate. This is said to yield the triiodide ion and the white precipitate of $\ce{Cu2I2}$.

I haven't been able to find a proper name for, or any data on this copper iodide... dimer? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(I)_iodide) mentions that it exists in several crystalline forms, so is it something that arises in that context? Or is it just an obscure dimer of copper iodide?

Comment: [Related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67492/are-cucl-and-cu2cl2-equivalent). Moreover, when coordinated with monodentate ligands, copper(I) halides can form cyclic dimers, tetramers, zigzag or ladder shaped polymers. See these pdfs: http://polymer.chem.cmu.edu/~kmatweb/2000/October_00/Inorg.Chem/3.pdf ... https://scholarworks.wm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1578&context=honorstheses

Comment: Cu2I2 in this context is just an unnecessarily complicated way to write CuI.

Comment: @IvanNeretin [or more appropriate, $\ce{2CuI}$ ;)](https://www.quora.com/Is-2CuI-same-as-Cu2I2)

Comment: @NilayGhosh: I saw that exact Quora answer, but he was talking about molecular beams, which (though I know nothing about them) sound way different from anything you'd see with these reaction conditions.